# Preparing the corpus for n-gram model word prediction in R

Tags: r, text, text-mining

I have the following function to predict the next word using `trigrams`. The libraries that I am using are: `ngrams`, `RWeka` and `tm`.

```
f <- function(queryHistoryTab, query, n = 2) {
  require(tau)
  trigrams <- sort(textcnt(rep(tolower(names(queryHistoryTab)), queryHistoryTab), method = "string", n = length(scan(text = query, what = "character", quiet = TRUE)) + 1))
  query <- tolower(query)
  idx <- which(substr(names(trigrams), 0, nchar(query)) == query)
  res <- head(names(sort(trigrams[idx], decreasing = TRUE)), n)
  res <- substr(res, nchar(query) + 2, nchar(res))
  return(res)
}
```

In order to feed the function I have to set a corpus. For this purpose I am using a data sets that consists in textual data extracted from US blogs:

```
text1 <- readLines("en_US.news.txt", encoding = "UTF-8")
corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(text1))
```

The class of the corpus is

```
>class(corpus)
[1] "VCorpus" "Corpus"
```

Nevertheless, when I am trying guess the two most common of words of a sentence I get the following error:

```
f(corpus, "I will like a")
 Error in textcnt(rep(tolower(names(queryHistoryTab)), queryHistoryTab),  : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'integer'
```

Here are the first lines of the `en_US.news.txt` in case you want to test it yourselves:

```
In the years thereafter, most of the Oil fields and platforms were named after pagan “gods”.
We love you Mr. Brown.
Chad has been awesome with the kids and holding down the fort while I work later than usual! The kids have been busy together playing Skylander on the XBox together, after Kyan cashed in his $$$ from his piggy bank. He wanted that game so bad and used his gift card from his birthday he has been saving and the money to get it (he never taps into that thing either, that is how we know he wanted it so bad). We made him count all of his money to make sure that he had enough! It was very cute to watch his reaction when he realized he did! He also does a very good job of letting Lola feel like she is playing too, by letting her switch out the characters! She loves it almost as much as him.
so anyways, i am going to share some home decor inspiration that i have been storing in my folder on the puter. i have all these amazing images stored away ready to come to life when we get our home.
With graduation season right around the corner, Nancy has whipped up a fun set to help you out with not only your graduation cards and gifts, but any occasion that brings on a change in one's life. I stamped the images in Memento Tuxedo Black and cut them out with circle Nestabilities. I embossed the kraft and red cardstock with TE's new Stars Impressions Plate, which is double sided and gives you 2 fantastic patterns. You can see how to use the Impressions Plates in this tutorial Taylor created. Just one pass through your die cut machine using the Embossing Pad Kit is all you need to do - super easy!
If you have an alternative argument, let's hear it! :)
```

Comment: Consider to use text2vec instead: http://text2vec.org/vectorization.html

Comment: You are passing in `queryHistoryTab`, a corpus object which is probably a type of list, as the second argument to `rep`, which expects an integer.